# How to update version in package.json

Tags: node.js, angular

I need to update the version by reading it from package J SON file which will be 1.1.1. After reading i need to append the build number with it like 1.1.1-1 and then i want to update the version field within the package J SON file. How i can achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fs.readFile() and fs.writeFile() to read and edit the package.json file.

append-build-to-version.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./package.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    var packageJsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
    var build = 5; // get this from somewhere or increment the last char
    var versionNumber = packageJsonObj.version;
    packageJsonObj.version = `${versionNumber}-${build}`;
    packageJsonObj = JSON.stringify(packageJsonObj);

    fs.writeFile('./package.json', packageJsonObj, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });
});
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "teststackoverflow",
    "version": "1.0.0-5",
    "description": "",
    "main": "router.js",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

More info on fs.readFile() and  fs.writeFile() can be found in the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback).

Comment: I need to attach build number with the version like 1.2.1-5 and here 5 is the build number.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. :)

Comment: I need to pass build variable as a pararmeter to this file instead of hard coded value. So that i can execute it in the NPM script.

Comment: how to format the output? after update, the content display in one line

Answer (score 5):

You can use
`npm version <YOUR VERSION>`

To increment versions use:

`npm version major` for major versions and

`npm version minor` For minor versions and

`npm version patch` For bug fixes

Comment: he is not talking about npm version lol